# Scrolling down the 3D object reloads the web page in mobile version but working fine in PC web browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, 3d, babylonjs

I am trying to use Babylon JS with angular 2 for developing a cross platform 3D viewer. I am able to reproduce some basic 3D images. The problem I am facing is that in PC web browser the 3D image can be rotated as users wish, if it comes to mobile version, when I try to scroll down the 3D image the whole page gets reloaded. Any help would be appriciable.

**users.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{

  ngOnInit()
  {
    var canvas : HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("renderBabylon");
    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas,true);

    var createScene = function(){
      // create a basic BJS Scene object
      var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
      // create a FreeCamera, and set its position to (x:0, y:5, z:-10)
      var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera('camera1', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5,-10), scene);
      // target the camera to scene origin
      camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
      // attach the camera to the canvas
      camera.attachControl(canvas, false);
      // create a basic light, aiming 0,1,0 - meaning, to the sky
      var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight('light1', new BABYLON.Vector3(-0.1,0,0), scene);
      // create a built-in "sphere" shape; its constructor takes 6 params: name, segment, diameter, scene, updatable, sideOrientation
      var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere('sphere1', 16, 2, scene);
      // move the sphere upward 1/2 of its height
      sphere.position.y = 1;
      // create a built-in "ground" shape; its constructor takes the same 6 params : name, width, height, subdivision, scene, updatable
      var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGround('ground1', 6, 6, 2, scene);
      // return the created scene
      return scene;
    }
// call the createScene function
    var scene = createScene();
// run the render loop
    engine.runRenderLoop(function(){
      scene.render();
    });
   // the canvas/window resize event handler
   // window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
   //   engine.resize();
   // });
  }
}
```

**users.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">

    <canvas id="renderBabylon"></canvas>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution by adding some script in index.html which prevents the basic properties of the browser which in turn prevented reloading and rubber band scroll effect.

**index.html**

```
<body>
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    window.onresize = function () {
        $(document.body).width(window.innerWidth).height(window.innerHeight);
    }
</script>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```